# R's predict.DArch example provides error "trying to get slot "data" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots"

Tags: r

Looking at v0.12 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/darch/darch.pdf I am using the example given for predict.DArch

```
library(darch)

data(iris)
model <- darch(Species ~ ., iris, retainData = T)
predict(model)
```

However, I receive an error:

```
WARN [2016-11-13 19:24:17] gputools package not available, using CPU matrix multiplication.
INFO [2016-11-13 19:24:17] Constructing a darch with 3 layers.
INFO [2016-11-13 19:24:17] Generating RBMs.
INFO [2016-11-13 19:24:17] Construct new RBM instance with 4 visible and 10 hidden units.
INFO [2016-11-13 19:24:17] Construct new RBM instance with 10 visible and 3 hidden units.
Error in getExecuteFunction(darch)(darch, dataSet@data) : 
  trying to get slot "data" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

Any idea on how I can resolve this?

Comment: I don't get any error by running the code on R 3.3.1.  If you have an earlier version of R, please update to newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded R to 3.3.2 and it works fine now.  Thanks.